# rearrange student roll number when a student or goes from the php using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

friends i am working on school management system project in php. the project almost completed. but the problem is if a new student enrolled or goes out from the class how can we rearrange the students roll number.

means a class have students like

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     roll         |  name            |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       1             |     1            |  abi             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       2             |     2            |  bibin           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       3             |     3            |  david           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

etc...

when a new student enrolled name "abhishek",we need to add between abi and bibin. also when a student goes from the class named 'bibin' ,we need to rearrange the roll number of each student.. how can we rearrange the students using php.

i have a array like this

```
   array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(9) {
        ["id"]=>string(2) "1"
        ["rvsm_class"]=> string(3) "ukg"
        ["rvsm_rollno"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["rvsm_name"]=> string(5) "Abi"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(9) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "2"
        ["rvsm_class"]=> string(3) "ukg"
        ["rvsm_rollno"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["rvsm_name"]=> string(5) "bibin"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(9) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "3"
        ["rvsm_class"]=> string(3) "ukg"
        ["rvsm_rollno"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["rvsm_name"]=> string(4) "david"
      }
    }
```

can anybody help me ....

Comment: Why do you need to change roll number?

Comment: when a new student enrolled or a student goes from the class. we need to rearrange the roll number of each student.. right ?

Comment: Why, surely the roll number is a unique id for the student, it should not change

Comment: I don't recommend your approach, as Riggs said, just assign a unique unchangeable id for each student.

Comment: Please accept the answer below, If it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I also not recommending the roll number should change. But if you still want to change than below code will helps you out:

```
$student_arr = array(
    array("id" => 1, "rvsm_class" => "ukg", "rvsm_rollno" => 1, "rvsm_name" => "Abi"),
    array("id" => 2, "rvsm_class" => "ukg", "rvsm_rollno" => 2, "rvsm_name" => "bibin"),
    array("id" => 3, "rvsm_class" => "ukg", "rvsm_rollno" => 3, "rvsm_name" => "david"),
    array("id" => 4, "rvsm_class" => "ukg", "rvsm_rollno" => 4, "rvsm_name" => "Abhi"),
    );

    function sortByName($a, $b) {

        return strcmp($a['rvsm_name'],$b['rvsm_name']);
    }

    usort($student_arr, 'sortByName');
    $cnt=1;
    $updatedArr = array();
    foreach($student_arr as &$value){    
        $value['rvsm_rollno'] = $cnt++;    
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($student_arr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [rvsm_class] => ukg
            [rvsm_rollno] => 1
            [rvsm_name] => Abhi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [rvsm_class] => ukg
            [rvsm_rollno] => 2
            [rvsm_name] => Abi
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [rvsm_class] => ukg
            [rvsm_rollno] => 3
            [rvsm_name] => bibin
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [rvsm_class] => ukg
            [rvsm_rollno] => 4
            [rvsm_name] => david
        )

)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you retrieve your students from a database. You can simply use something like

`SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY class,name;`

So you don't have to bother to re-arrange arrays in PHP.